# A code meant to delete multiple rows (to improve processing speed) on condition is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-macros

On my column D there are two values - exp and ok; I am meant to remove all exp rows but there are sometimes 1000's and the macro takes ages to complete.

So from the normal macro - deleting 1 row at a time, I'm trying to delete multimple rows.

```
function expirate_removed(){



  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activesheet = app.getActiveSheet()


  var r = activesheet.getRange('D:D');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)


    if( v[0,i-50]=='exp')
      activesheet.deleteRows(i-50, 50);

};
```

I have previously recorded a macro sorting the sheet, making sure all the exp ones are at the bottom, thinking this would help me save a few good minute.

Problem is, whenever I run the macro it deltes one set of 50' rows and then it gives an error saying the rows are out of bounds..

Any suggestions? ( I already have a working version for deleting one row at a time)

Comment: Youl need to remove 50 from your length after each iteration.

Comment: Make `i--50` instead of `i--` in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column D is sorted, try this:

```
function expirate_removed(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activesheet = app.getActiveSheet();

  var r = activesheet.getRange('D:D');
  var v = r.getValues();

  var startRow = 0;
  var endRow = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
    if(v[i] == 'ok'){
      startRow = i+1;
      break;
    }
  }

  for(var i=startRow; i<v.length; i++) {
    if(v[i] != 'ok'){
      endRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  activesheet.deleteRows(startRow, endRow - startRow + 1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my understanding is wrong but you could use the mapping which helps you to get faster.

```
    function expirate_removed(){
      var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var activesheet = app.getActiveSheet();

      var values = activesheet.getRange(1,5,activesheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
      var mapValues = values.map(function(r){return r[0]});
      mapValues.forEach(function(elt,index){
      if(elt == "exp"){
     activesheet.deleteRow(index);

}
});
```